# Webpack error " ValidationError: Invalid parser object"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

After update to `webpack 5` I have this error:

```
Module not found: ValidationError: Invalid parser object. Json Modules Plugin has been initialized using a parser object that does not match the API schema.- parser has an unknown property 'amd'. These properties are valid:  object { parse? }
```

webpack 5.68.0

Comment: Can you share your Webpack configuration?

Answer (score 2):

My bad Im lost in my code this:

```
parser: {
      amd: false,
    },
```

Without this its works